# Accurately compare dates from different timezones with zeroed time

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to check if two things happen on the same date but am having a small bit of trouble.

Using the Xero API, I get a list of payroll calendars which each have a start time and an end time, and those times are returned as Y-m-d with hours/minutes/seconds zeroed out, with Timezone Australia/Sydney as follows:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2018-05-01 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Australia/Sydney )
```

I get a list of recent Timesheets for an employee, and they have a start and end date that should match up with the payroll calendar period - but they're returning as timezone Z (Zulu?) and again with the time zeroed, as such:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z )
```

I swear I googled around before I asked here but I'll ask anyway:

How can I compare these two dates? I tried creating a new DateTime from startDate->format('Y-m-d'), I tried setting the timezone to Zulu (was out by obviously 10 hours), tried creating a new DateTime from a clone of the Zulu time where I set the timezone and then got just the Y-m-d part of it... Something that "works" is to clone the date, set the timezone, then set the time to 0...
Like this:

```
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $calendar->getStartDate()->format('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"))->setTime(0,0);
```

Is there a better and neater way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but I'll assume that you just want to determine whether the two dates are the same, after they have been adjusted for the timezone offset.

Using the two `DateTime` objects simply call `DateTime::diff`. If the number of days difference is zero, the two dates are the same (ignoring the time).

```
// Payroll date
$p = new DateTime('2018-05-01 00:00:00.000000', new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));

// Timesheet date
$t = new DateTime('2018-04-30 00:00:00.000000', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

var_dump($t->diff($p)->days === 0); // same
```

Comment: If they're already `DateTime` objects, with the correct `DateTimeZone` already set, then all you need to do is diff the dates, per the last line of code.

Comment: They're datetime objects, with different timezones, with zero time.

Comment: The main problem I suppose is that it's ugly, but if that's how it is that's how it is I suppose.

Comment: What's ugly? It's one line of code - `$t->diff($p)->days === 0`

Comment: if($calendar->getStartDate()->diff($entry->getStartDate())->days === 0 && $endDate->diff($entry->getEndDate())->days === 0) {